# Организация тестирования с большой базой данных

Tags: sql, база-данных, sql-server, оптимизация

Есть команда web-разработчиков около 50 человек. Web приложение работает с БД. Каждый разворачивает тестовую MS SQL базу данных для своей разработки. Каждая БД очень большая (около 1 TB). В итоге имеем большие проблемы со свободным местом. Шринк особо не спасает. Сейчас уже очень дорого разделять БД на отдельные "модульные" БД. Хранение таблиц и индексов уже оптимизировали (например, с помощью Columnstore).

Есть такая идея: делать особый бэкап, в котором вырезать всю "мертвую" информацию (письма, логи, файлы), и потом уже восстанавливать тестовый стенд из него.

Помогите, пожалуйста, советом. Нормально ли такое решение? Какие есть практики организации работы в таких ситуациях? Может есть какое-нибудь подходящая методология, чтобы изучить?

Comment: прям каждому своя копия нужна?

Comment: Да, разработка у каждого своя. Каждый меняет схему. Никак не пересекается, что удобно.

Answer (score 0):

Смотрите, еслиу Вас проблема именно с МЕСТОМ, то можно попробовать вот что.

Я осознаю, что идея выглядит немного безумной, но задачу с местом она решит.

Делаем один центральный сервер.

На нём кладём некую "исходную" базу данных в файловую систему с блочной дедупликацией. (Мне нравится ZFS, но можно попробовать, например, BTRFS)

Создаём 50 её копий, запущенных на 50 SQL серверах. К каждому из них подключается разрботчик, и начинает эту базу менять.

База данных хранит все данные в "страницах". (по моему, в MS SQL размер страницы - 8 мб).

Из за того, что используется блочная дедупликация - то все страницы всех баз данных, в которых не происхоило изменений - будут храниться на диске только в одном экземпляре.

А "разница" - то есть, новые страниц или страницы с переписанными (относительно исходной БД) данными - это и будет тот "прирост места", котрый возникнет в процессе работы.

Я почти уверен, что в базе такого объема большая часть страниц использутся без модификации данных. Их только читают из базы.

Соответственно, все довольны: у каждого разработчика своя база, все базы в совокупности занимают место как одна + сумма изменённых в них данных.

А 50 отдельных SQL серверов - это всего лишь 50 докер-контейнеров, в общем то, не очень много для сервера.

Comment: Спасибо за интересную идею. Я правильно вас понял, что архитектура у всех одна? Если так, то один может переименовать таблицу и у другого всё сломается?

Comment: Нет, у каждого своя полноценная база данных. То есть, файл на диске с образом базы, память, в которой работает сервер, сам процесс сервера - всё своё и отдельное, независимое.
Но из за дедупликации все 50 экземпляров файла базы данных занимают столько же места, сколько всего один - потому что "copy on change".
Продолжая рассуждения, при переименовании базы происходит не физческо перемещение данных, а изменение в системной области. Все страницы с данными остались на месте - место не увеличилось.
Практически, самым "жрущим место" дейсвием будет перестроение кластерного индекса

Comment: Наверное, вы имели в виду что-то вроде [Borg](https://borgbackup.readthedocs.io/en/stable/). Правда, Borg для бакапов, вряд ли его возможно адаптировать под использование в реальном времени.

Comment: @DiD - я посмотрел, по диагонали. Я бы сказал - что Borg пользуется теми же преимуществами дедупликации, котрыми хотел бы воспользоваться и я. А вообще - что Вы думаете, Вам кажется предлагаемая мной схема не рабочей?

Comment: Схема рабочая, в качестве экономии места это было бы первое что надо сделать. Правда, я не встречал систем дедупликации с доступом к данным в реальном времени. Метод очень хорош для консервирования данных и используется такими популярными средствами как, например, Apple Time Machine и Time Capsule. Но я боюсь, MSSQL будет сложно подружить с методом. При этом, если разделить БД на актуальные и  архивные данные, эта схема будет иметь место независимо от деятельности ИТ-предприятия и легко впишется в любую организацию.

Comment: @DiD - спасибо за Ваш отзыв, мне даже стало немного лестно. Если говорить о дедупликации в реальном времени - то я немного возился с ZFS - и там это работает. памяти, правда, жрет (около 8 мб опертивы на 1 гигабайт диска с дедупликацией) - но работает.

Comment: @DiD Кстати, есть вот такой очень интересный проект zfs под винду: https://github.com/openzfsonwindows/ZFSin , и описание: https://habr.com/ru/post/374317/

Comment: А у меня с ZFS были трудности с производительностью... Возможно, просто не разобрался до конца. С Ext4 мой компьютер загружался от загрузки ядра до готовности к работе где-то за 11 секунд, а с ZFS грузился минут 3-5 , иногда 10 (Это было давненько, еще до ZombieLoad. Процессор Skylake 6770HQ, 32Gb RAM, 2 х 1Tb Intel 600p). Вот тогда то я понял о чем говорил Линус Торвальдс.

Comment: @DiD - ну, на то, чтобы с zfs грузиться - я не решился... использовал её только для storage - и вроде было все нормально. Думаю, что долгую загрузку с zfs диагностировать сейчас уже поздно :-) - компьютера то под рукой нет, чтобы хотя бы посмотреть dmesg

Comment: @S.H. я нашел для вас [логи](https://linux-hardware.org/?probe=3a83d976d0) внизу страницы под списком устройств вы найдете ссылки на все логи. Например, [boot.log](https://linux-hardware.org/?probe=3a83d976d0&log=boot.log) показывает, кто компьютер загружался около 10 минут. [dmesg](https://linux-hardware.org/?probe=3a83d976d0&log=dmesg) тоже есть. И это не единственные логи, на этом сайте если покопаться, таких случае сотни.

Comment: @DiD - круто, я, конечно, гляну, хотя могу - ну, всякое бывает - ничего и не понять. Если что то более-менее очевидное - я отпишусь в комментариях!